# Distinct Date and DateTime in MVC.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I would like to differentiate a Date to a DateTime like :

```
public class ViewModel {
    public Date Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, i would like call this :

```
@Html.EditorFor(p => Model.Date)
@Html.EditorFor(p => Model.DateTime)
```

to render :

```
<input data-val="true" data-rule-date="true" data-val-date="Must be a date." type="date" value="" aria-describedby="field-error"/>
<input data-val="true" data-rule-datetime="true" data-val-date="Must be a datetime." type="datetime" value="" aria-describedby="field-error"/>
```

The reason I want to do this, is to have 2 differents plugin initialisation and validation methods, using datepicker and jquery validate plugins, like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.addMethod("date", function(value, element) { [date validation code] });
    $("[type='date']").datepicker({ format:"dd/MM/yyyy" });

    $.validator.addMethod("datetime", function(value, element) { [time validation code] });
    $("[type='datetime']").datetimepicker({ format:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" });
</script>
```

My question is : Am i obliged to declare a new struct `Date` and his `Html.EditorFor` implementation or there is a simpler way ?

Comment: Have you considered display formatting options for DateTime properties? Attempting to make a new Type yourself might prove to be a needless headache later, given DateTime is implemented nearly everywhere/every language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change what type this are represented as when rendered with the HTMLHelper by using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` above the fields in your model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: Type Date is undefined, you mean `public DateTime Date` instead no ?

Comment: @GGO Yes sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to an EditorTemplate using an `[UIHint]` attribute in the ViewModel. No `Date` struct is needed.

```
public class ViewModel {
    [UIHint("Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

With this declaration, `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)` will look for an EditorTemplate named `Date.cshtml` and pass a `DateTime` as model to this editor.

For more see: [UIHint, DisplayTemplates, and EditorTemplates in MVC](https://blog.robseder.com/2012/06/01/uihint-displaytemplates-and-editortemplates-in-mvc/).